# QR codes in Windows Phone 7 or 7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

I need a library or tutorial about working with QR codes (bidimensional bar codes) in Windows Phone 7. Any Idea or suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this Nokia community blog tutorial on a QR code sample for Windows Phone http://www.developer.nokia.com/Blogs/Community/2012/12/02/mashape-api-how-to-consume-in-wp/

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at this tutorial: http://jonas.follesoe.no/2011/07/22/qr-code-scanning-on-windows-phone-75-using-zxlib/ which uses a Silverlight/Windows Phone port of [ZXing library](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)